# how to use cordova inappbrowser plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

I am developing a mobile app with apache cordova. This is a very simple app which loads responsive website. For now, I am using the HTML  tag to load the page, but I want to use the Cordova inappbrower for this purpose.

This is my www/index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body style="width: 100%;height: 100%;overflow: hidden;">
    <iframe style="width: 100%;height: 100%; border: none;" height="100%" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/"></iframe>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my www/js/index.js file:

```
var app = {

    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {

      var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

            var states = {};
            states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
            states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
            states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
            states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
            states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

            if ((states[networkState]) == states[Connection.NONE])
            {
            window.location.href="noconnection.html"; 
            } else {
            this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
            }
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Please Help. I have installed the inappbrowser but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

To do a quick test you can try

```
window.open("http://www.mywebsite.com/", "_blank");
```